# Why does the operator ** fail where the operator ^ works?

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

So, here are two list comprehensions, first uses `^` while second uses `**`:

```
> [x ^ 2 | x <- [1..10], odd x]
[1,9,25,49,81]
> [x ** 2 | x <- [1..10], odd x]

<interactive>:9:1:
    No instance for (Show t0) arising from a use of ‘print’
    The type variable ‘t0’ is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Show Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
      instance Show Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
      instance (Integral a, Show a) => Show (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
      ...plus 23 others
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

As far as I know difference between the two operators is that first works with integers, while second works with floating point values. Expected output then:

```
[1.0,9.0,25.0,49.0,81.0]
```

Actual question is: why does the second list comprehension fail?

Comment: So what are the types of `(^)` and `(**)`?  You can find this out with the `:type` or `:t` command in GHCi.

Comment: @bheklilr, `(^) :: (Num a, Integral b) => a -> b -> a` and `(**) :: Floating a => a -> a -> a`... However I can do: `10 ^ 2` as well as `10 ** 2` in GHCi. First gives output `100` and the second gives output `100.0`. If I remove condition `odd x` both comprehensions work... strange...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say `**` works with floating ponints. However `odd` only works with `Integral`s. Therefore your second list comprehension only works with types that are instances of both `Floating` and `Integral` and such a type does not exist.

However I'm not sure why the error message claims that there are 26 possible instances when none of the instances it mentions actually meet the required constraints.

Comment: Hmm... I thought when `odd x` takes place `x` is an integer from source list... Or does Haskell consider the list `[1..10]` being of type `Floating` automatically?

Comment: @Mark Haskell considers `[1..10]` to be whatever instance of `Num a => [a]` you need it to be. In your case you do `x ** 2`, which tells Haskell that `x` must be an instance of `Floating` and therefore `[1..10]` must be an instance of `Floating a => [a]`.